# fancy data entry, validation and layout within a textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

I like what these people are doing with copy/paste data entry, validation and layout within a textarea.  I seems to go beyond common form validation models.

http://batchgeo.com/

Can anyone suggest a js library or some reading on this subject?

Their geo-mapping is also impressive but not as mysterious.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is actually very simple. If you use Chrome, Firefox, Safari inspector you can see the layout and the mark-up they have used. What they have done is use a text area and a table. The table is used for the column table layout, and the text area when you clickso you to paste, type data in

The text area and the table are switched when you click. Basically one is hidden and one is shown. For the we just toggle some css on both elements, the table is switched out the text area is switch in, see the fiddle below.

The data in the tables is fed into both views, the table view and the text area view. The text in the text area view uses hidden tab codes to space the text. When you type in some text, they have some java-script that formats, or attempts to format that data into columns. this is a kind of CSV parser, after it has detected columns in the data it constructs another table with columns and rows to match your data, for this they make a new table in code, append the rows or edit the example one. I would probably just make a new table and switch that one in. I have not added this in the example as it would be too much code.

The hardest part is possibly the css styling, making the table fix the size of the text area, making the text and columns match. You can add scroll bars to both the text area and the table (using a surrounding scrolling div) this is shown in my example.

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="ta" onClick="toggle(this)" class="spreadsheet hide">

//...text version goes here    

</textarea>

 <div id="tb" onClick="toggle(this)" class="spreadsheet">
 <table>
   //..table rows and cols go here 
 </table> 
 </div>
```

**see the working fiddle for code and css**

http://jsfiddle.net/8knfa56b/2/

It is just a quick example of how it is done, It is not near perfect, but with a little love and time it can be done.

Comment: that's a great start, but there is more there. They are capturing data and parsing on tabs, then doing validations.